# dt-picker не влазит в блок после открытия

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка

Как сделать, чтобы при открытии ДТ-пиккер влазил нормально?? только с помощью js???

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    
    $('[id^=datetimepicker]').datetimepicker();
    $("#archivePayments").modal("show");
    
    });
```

```html
<?php 
    session_start();
    
    
    if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) 
    {
        header("Location: );
    }
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://rawgit.com/tempusdominus/bootstrap-4/master/build/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.css">
 </head>
    <body>
      
  
  <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade p-0" id="archivePayments" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="confirmPhoneTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <!-- <div class="modal-dialog-centered col-11 col-md-8 px-0 mx-auto" role="document"> -->
    <div class="modal-dialog-centered modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-scrollable" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header">
       <h5 class="modal-title" id="archivePaymentsTitle">Архів платежів</h5>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-header" >
       <div class="form-row w-100">
       <div class="col-12 col-lg">
       <div class="form-group">
       <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker_start" data-target-input="nearest">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
         <div class="input-group-text">З</div>
       </div>
         <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#datetimepicker_start" data-toggle="datetimepicker" />
         <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#datetimepicker_start" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
        <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
         </div>
       </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg">
         <div class="form-group">
       <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker_finish" data-target-input="nearest">
       <div class="input-group-prepend">
         <div class="input-group-text">До</div>
       </div>
         <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#datetimepicker_finish" data-toggle="datetimepicker" />
         <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#datetimepicker_finish" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
        <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
         </div>
       </div>
        </div>
         </div>
       </div>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-body" >
       
       </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  
  
  
  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/moment@2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/tempusdominus/bootstrap-4/master/build/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```